# Redux toolkit - Cannot use 'in' operator error on upsertMany

Tags: redux, normalizr, redux-toolkit

I am following the docs to `upsertMany` into my redux `createSlice`.

I am following [this](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-guide#using-createentityadapter-with-normalization-libraries) part of the docs.

I keep getting this error in my `upsertMany` call. **Why is this?**

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '525' in undefined
```

I have noticed that normalizr returns both `entities` and `result` objects, however, RTK only uses `entities`. Where do we use the `result` if we need to at all?

**Here is my createSlice**

```
const posts = new schema.Entity('actionPosts', {}, { idAttribute: 'id' })

export const fetchPosts = createAsyncThunk(
  'actionPosts/fetchPosts',
  async (email) => {
    const { data } = await getUserActionPostsByUser({ email })
    const extractedPosts = data.userActionPostsByUser
    const normalizedData = normalize(extractedPosts, [posts])
    return normalizedData.entities
  }
)

const adapter = createEntityAdapter({
  sortComparer: (a, b) => b.createdAt.localeCompare(a.createdAt),
  loading: '',
  error: '',
})

const initialState = adapter.getInitialState()

const slice = createSlice({
  name: 'actionPosts',
  initialState,
  extraReducers: {
    [fetchPosts.fulfilled]: (state, { payload }) => {
      console.log('payload', payload.actionPosts)
      adapter.upsertMany(state, payload.actionPosts) // error happens here
    },
  },
})

export default slice.reducer
```

**Here is the normalized object**

```
{
  actionPosts: {
      525: {
        id: 525
        email: "test@test.com"
        content: "lorem ipsum"
        createdAt: "2020-09-24T20:29:44.848Z"
      }
    }
  result[
    525,
  ]
}
```

Comment: If you can post a reproducible demo I can look at it.  The exact error `Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '525' in undefined` happens when `state` is missing the `ids` property.  It would happen if you didn't set an `initialState`, but it seems like you have so I'm unsure why you are seeing that error.